# generating a random probability mass function with uniform $p_i$'s

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like to find the random probability mass function of a tuple $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n)$ such that each variable is distributed such that $$p_i \sim U(0,1)$$ individually, but that every tuple satisfies $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{p_i}=1$$.

What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: Are the $p_i$ random variables here? If so then then $(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ is a random vector. How can it be a PMF?

Comment: its a random vector of non-negative entries which sums to 1. If it sums to 1 then any one of its realization can used as a PMF.

Comment: @drhab It can be a random PMF, as is usual in Bayesian statistics. Unfortunately, there is another, more serious, problem with the idea...

Comment: and what is that Did. Please explain.

Comment: @Iconoclast ?? Done for 21 minutes when you posted this comment.

Comment: your comments and answer came out of chronological order on my browswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p_i$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, then $E(p_i)=\frac12$. If $p_1+\cdots+p_n=1$ then $E(p_1)+\cdots+E(p_n)=1$. If both properties hold, then $n\cdot\frac12=1$ hence $n=2$. Conversely, what you ask is impossible if $n\ne2$.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that there was something wrong. It is from a paper on Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods for MIMO wireless systems. Evidently the authors made a mistake.

Comment: Are you sure they ask every $p_i$ to be uniform? Or rather, some beta?

Comment: Yup they ask every $p_i$ to be uniform. I double checked.

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: Check http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6034. page 7. sorry for the late response. was a bit busy. Let me know if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: Well, you transcribed the thing correctly, as far as I can tell... so this appears to be an oversight from the authors. A way out would be to draw $n$ i.i.d. uniform $U_i$ and to consider the ratios $p_i=U_i/(U_1+\cdots+U_n)$. My guess is that this would fit the rest of the paper (but I did not chack).

Comment: I am going to check the algorithm with this choice of $p_i$ to see if it gives the results shown in the paper. Its an IEEE transactin paper, should not have such a slip!